# How to remove sites from best results

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, history, browser-history

I have cleared my history in Safari and in my settings, but I still get annoying recommended websites even though I only put 1 letter in and I don't want that site in there any more.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to our site! :) Can I suggest you edit your question to clarify it somewhat? At present your question title and the actual question can be interpreted as referring to *different* aspects of Safari. It's also not clear what you actually did in Settings, and knowing that would be good to ensure you're not getting answers telling you to do something you've already tried.

Comment: Go to **Settings** > **Safari** and change your settings.